# Smarty comment stripping and KnockoutJS

Tags: knockout.js, smarty, smarty3, html

I'm trying to use KnockoutJS in my web framework, which uses plain Smarty.

Some parts of KnockoutJS's syntax use comments in the form of `<!-- ko foreach: array -->`.

Smarty strips all HTML comments (except IE conditionals), including these ones.

I can remove the responsible `preg_replace` line in Smarty, but I'd rather have solution where I don't have to change third party code.

Is there any way to skip the comment stripping in Smarty?

Answer (score 0):

Actually Smarty displays all HTML comments such as `<!-- comment -->` in the final output of the template. Only the Smarty-specific comments `{* this is a comment *}` are hidden in the final output. Your framework may be hiding the HTML comments in the back-end, perhaps for HTML compression.

Refer to [Smarty Comment Syntax](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.basic.syntax.tpl)

Comment: You may be using an old version. The current version (3.1.13, and several versions back) have a plugin named `outputfilter.trimwhitespace.php`, which contains a line `$source = preg_replace( '#<!--.*?-->#ms', '', $source );`, which does the comment stripping. As far as I know, the filter cannot be disabled or removed without altering code or removing the file.

Comment: I apologize. I had little idea about the new plugin.

Comment: Martijn is incorrect, outputfilter.trimwhitespace.php is not enabled OOTB. It must be explicitly enabled in the PHP code. You could simply not enable it.